# How to convert json data to html from controller to view using ajax datatable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, datatables

I have a controller that contains sample for table in string format and returns it as a JSON response to `index.blade.php`

After that, I use [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) with AJAX-option to get the data and, upon success, it should convert the JSON format to a normal table in HTML.

I still don't understand how this works unless you guys show me how. Please help.

Here's my script code (\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php):

```
var table1 = $('#table1').DataTable(
            {   
                ajax:{
                    url:'/',
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(data){
                        $('.table1display').html(data);
                        //console.log(data);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here's the HTML code (\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')  

    <div class="table1display"></div>

@endsection
```

Here's my controller code (\Controllers\PostController.php):

```
public function index()
{ 
   $getNote2 = DB::connection('mysql')->table('note2')->select('stockcode', 'note')->orderBy('stockcode', 'ASC')->get();

   $display = '';

   $display .= "<table id='table1' class='cell-border wrap' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                   <thead>
                      <tr>
                         <th>Test</th>
                      </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>";

                   foreach ($getNote2 as $val)
                   {
                      $display .= "<tr>
                                      <td>".($val->stockcode)."</td>
                                  </tr>";
                   }

  $display .="</body></table>";

  return response()->json($display) ;
}
```

Here's my route code:

```
Route::get('/', 'PostController@index');
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer as this thread has turned into mess, hope you had a chance to read it and follow my suggestions, because cooking up HTML to populate DataTables is always a bad idea.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg Okay. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to get your view, or frontend,  separated from your backend. I think it is a bad idea to create the view inside the controller. So, with that in mind, you had to return only the value from you database and working with it in your view with JS.

For example, in you controller you may do following changes:

```
public function index()
{ 
   $getNote2 = DB::connection('mysql')->table('note2')->select('stockcode', 'note')->orderBy('stockcode', 'ASC')->get();

  return response()->json($getNote2) ;
}
```

After that you have to create the table in the view. You have several options, like create all the table or maybe you can have the table prepared in you html code.

For example:

Here's the html of index.blade.php code

```
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">stockcode</th>
      <th scope="col">note</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id = "table1">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

And finally in you js code

```
var table1 = $('#table1').DataTable(
        {   
            ajax:{
                url:'/',
                type:"GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){
                   //Here you can use a for to work with the data, but is better working with es6, so im doing with map

data.map(function(dataValue) {


   var tr = document.createElement('tr');
   var td1 = document.createElement('td');
   var text1 = document.createTextNode(dataValue.stockcode);
   var text2 = document.createTextNode(dataValue.id);
   var td2 = document.createElement('td');

   td1.appendChild(text1);
   td2.appendChild(text2);
   tr.appendChild(td1);
   tr.appendChild(td2);

    var tbody =  document.getElementById('table1')



tbody.appendChild(tr); 

  })
   }
  }

 });
```

I dont test this code but its something like this. If you want to try, you can check a example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3frubLmg/

I hope this be useful. Happy code!!

Comment: It would be better if it can display with custom column and row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all of the correct scripts and styles loaded, there are a few issues with your existing code.

First, the routes don't make sense.  Your homepage `/` and `/posts` are both pointed at the same controller method `PostController@index`, and the AJAX calls the `/` route again, which is now supposed to return a JSON response?

Make yourself another controller, lets call it PageController.

```php
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }
}
```

Then lets change your routes to:

```php
// pages
Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');

// posts
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

Next, let's create another blade file to make it easier to manage your table layout. You accidentally had a closing `</body>` tag instead of `</tbody>` which would not work out well for you.  This would be easier to catch with code styling as opposed to being defined in the PHP as a string.

/resources/views/layouts/table.blade.php

```php
<table id='table1' class='cell-border wrap' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($getNote2 as $val)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $val->stockcode }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then clean up your PostController.  We'll actually render the new table blade file right here in the controller using the View facade.

```php
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class PostController  extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $getNote2 = DB::connection('mysql')->table('note2')->select('stockcode', 'note')->orderBy('stockcode', 'ASC')->get();

        $display = View::make('layouts.table',compact('getNote2'))->render();

        return response()->json($display);
    }

}
```

And finally complete your layout. This assumes you have a scripts section defined in your `/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` file.  And we'll change the AJAX to call the `/posts` route in order to receive our JSON response.

/resources/views/index.blade.php

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')  

    <div class="table1display"></div>

@endsection

@section('scripts')

    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/posts",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    // set your target node
                    var target = $('.table1display');
                    // log to console
                    console.log(data);
                    // hide table prior to styling
                    target.hide();
                    // load data in table
                    target.html(data);
                    // initialize DataTable
                    initializeDataTable();
                    // show table
                    target.show();
                }
            });
        });

        function initializeDataTable() {
            $('#table1').DataTable();
        }
    </script>

@endsection
```

And I think that should be it. Hope this helps and good luck!

**EDIT**

You asked:

> Is it possible to pass sql and mysql queries as json on submit button based on value inserted?

You **never** want to pass raw queries from the client side because anyone could change the query and steal, alter, or trash your data.

However, you can certainly submit new form values and build the query on the server side.

I have not tested this code, but I imagine you would do something like this:

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <!-- Form -->
    <form id="my_form">
        <input type="text" name="my_data" value=""/>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <!-- End Form -->

    <!-- Datatable -->
    <div class="table1display"></div>
    <!-- End Datatable -->

@endsection

@section('scripts')

    <script>

        // wait until document is fully loaded
        $(document).ready( function () {

            // update table with default form params
            updateTableData();
        });

        // listen for changes on input if you want to submit instantly
        // however, I really recommend you find and use a library 
        // such as lodash to debounce the inputs if you are going to do this
        $('input[name="my_data"]').on('keyup',function(e) {
            ('#my_form').submit();
        });

        // listen for form submission
        $('#my_form').submit(function(e) {

            // prevent the default form action since we didn't define one
            // otherwise it may try to reload the current page
            e.preventDefault();

            // update table with new form params
            updateTableData();
        });

        // we'll break this out into a self contained function that
        // takes the existing form data and builds a query accordingly
        function updateTableData() {

            // get the form data
            var data = $('#my_form').serialize();

            // your ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: "/posts?" + data,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                    // call our success function
                    successUpdateTable(data);
                }
            });
        }

        // now that you have the data
        // perform the actions to update the table
        function successUpdateTable(data) {
            // set your target node
            var target = $('.table1display');
            // log response to console
            console.log(data);
            // hide table prior to styling
            target.hide();
            // empty the table contents
            target.empty();
            // load data in table
            target.html(data);
            // initialize DataTable
            $('#table1').DataTable();
            // show table
            target.show();
        }

    </script>

@endsection
```

Then you would need to handle the filtering on the server side via the **Request** received.

```php
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class PostController  extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // validate your request
        // to make sure you received what you expected
        $request->validate([
            'my_data' => 'required'
        ]);

        // create your filter based on the request values
        // I cannot write this for you as only you know your data
        $getNote2 = '...';

        // render the table element
        $display = View::make('layouts.table',compact('getNote2'))->render();

        // send your response
        return response()->json($display);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass sql and mysql queries as `json` on `submit button` based on value inserted? So in my `datatable ajax success` will display the table? I need this to reload the ajax without refreshing the page everytime on event occur such as `onchange`,  `keyup` and `click` event. That would be great.

Comment: I have added to my initial response to answer your new question.  This should give you a good starting point.

Comment: how about for 2 separated query? For example like this : `View::make('layouts.table')->with('getNote2', $getNote2)->with('getNote3', $getNote3)->render();` ?

Comment: @Richmond : I'm not sure I understand, do you mean you want two different tables?

Comment: It's okay now. I already change everything to the default syntax by storing all the data to json and call in ajax datatables. Thank for the help.